# Finding a second order ODE from a system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of ODEs 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}'=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2& 3\\
-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with initial conditions 
$x(0)=1, y(0)=1$.

---

I'm used to going from a second order ODE to a system of equations using some sort of substitution, but going backwards, i.e. from a system to a single second order ODE, is not so intuitive.

How might I reduce this system to a single second order ODE in terms of $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our system is

$$x' = -2x + 3 y \\ y' = -x + 2 y \\ x(0) = 1, ~y(0) = 1$$

From the first equation, we have

$$x' = -2x + 3 y \implies y = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(x' + 2x\right)$$

We can also differentiate the first equation and have

$$x'' = -2 x' + 3 y' = -2 x' + 3(-x + 2 y)$$

Hopefully, you can take it from there.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, all that remains to do is to substitute $y$ into the $x''$? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, and then to use the first equation to find $x'(0)$ as a second IC in terms of $x$.